# How to connect Sapphire RX580 Nitro+ GPU to Corsair CX750M PSU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

The Sapphire RX580 GPU is a special edition and has an extra 6pin port. I'm just a little confused how to connect it properly. The CX750M PSU cam with two 6+2 wires but what confuses me is the wires also have a "piggy back" 6+2 wire. So i'm wondering if i should connect the 6 pin piggy back wire into the 6 pin port on the GPU or if i should connect another 6+2 cable to the PSU and run that to the GPU.

Below are some pictures to help you visualize.

What the cables look like:

(The PSU came with 2 of these cables)

[image: GPU PCIE CABLE]

[image: GPU]

[image: back of the CX750m]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graphics card needs both power connectors connected.

Go from the "6+2 PCIe" on your power supply. If you have two of these connectors on your PSU (the 650W version I just bought did) then out of preference you should plug one cable into each.

Put one of the 6+2 piggyback connectors together to make an 8 pin and fit in your graphics card 8 way power connector. It should only fit one way round as the connector plastic shrouds are keyed, but the retention clip should be pointing upwards on your photo.

Plug in the other 6 pin PCIe connector and leave the remaining "+2" part dangling or tie it back with a cable tie.

Comment: So just to be clear i understand. I don't need to use the piggy back? I should use two cables instead and just ignore the piggy back?

Comment: Sorry, you *should* use the piggyback in the 8 pin and only a 6 pin in the one that doesn't want it.

Comment: OK. So only 1 cable in total?

Comment: If your PSU has only one PCIe then yes, otherwise try to use both. Two connectors need to be fitted on the graphics card side.

Comment: My PSU looks exactly like the picture above.

Comment: I've purchased this card but it hasn't arrived yet, my PSU is 600W, can it handle the new GPU?